# Java: Inheritance, which container I should use to store the object passed by method

Tags: java

I am trying to structure classes comprises of inheritance. 
classes I have created

1. main
2. List item
3. library
4. item
5. person
6. books
7. MusicCD
8. Movies
9. Magazine ....etc

here is the library class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Library {
    /**
    * itemList contains the List of all items in the library. 
    */
private ArrayList itemList;

/**
 * count of all the items in the library. 
 */
private int count;

public Library(){

}

/**
 * Add a new item to the list of items. 
 * @param newItem The new item to be added to the list.
 * @throws unisa.library.DuplicateItemException
 */

public void addItem(Item newItem) throws DuplicateItemException {
    itemList.add(newItem);
}
```

}

Item class,

```
    public class Item extends Person{
private String id;
private String name;
private boolean loaned;
//borrower?
private double cost;


public Item(String id, String name, boolean loaned, String borrower, double cost) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(borrower);
    this.id = id;
    this.name=name;
    this.loaned = loaned;
    this.cost = cost;
}

public String getID(String id){
    return id;
}
public String getName(String name){
    return name;
}
public boolean getLoaned(boolean loaned){
    return loaned;
}
public double getCost(double cost){
    return cost;
}
```

}

person class,

```
    public class Person {

private String name;
private String address;
public Person(String name, String address){

    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
public Person(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

book, Movies, MusicCD  all are identical

```
    public class Book extends Item{
private String author;

public Book(String author, String id, String name, boolean loaned, String borrower, double cost){
    super(id, name, loaned, borrower, cost);
    this.author = author;
}
```

}

I must use these classes but I am not sure whether I have applied correct inheritance.

now the problem is from the main class
they are initiating library object

Do the Test

```
    Library l1 = new Library();
```

and calling method

```
    l1.addItem(new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID001","Vanity Not So Faire",      false,"New York", null, 5.95));
```

here they are passing object of Magazine class (identical to book class) and in the function declaration I have used Item as container. By addItem it is required to add any item (book, magazine, DVD ...etc). what container I should pass in the function declaration (addItem(?)) or Is there something wrong in structuring classes???

Comment: Why would `Item` extend `Person`?  It seems to me like `Item` is a generic object loaned out by the library (as evidenced by the fact that `Book`, `MusicCD`, etc. extend `Item`).  Does the `Library` loan out people?

Comment: Yes, Library loan out people. Here is my library class. I still stuck at addItem method of library class, Below I have shown my library and item class. problem is in item class constructor there String parameter of borrower name and the method addItemm called by main class which is passing all objects (like magazine, book, movie etc) so while defining addItem method in library class which class reference I should take to catch that object I cant take item class reference. I dont uderstand how to deal with it, I think if I can solve this whole program will be easy for me. refer classes below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing that i noticed wrong was why is an `Item` extending a `Person`..?

the next one is that if books,magazines and all the other stuff you say are having identical code, it breaks the concept of re-usability.

so, to summerize

Person class need not be extended by any other class but since he may borrow an item he may have a reference of Item in the class

```
public class Person {
  private ArrayList<Item> itemList;
  //more person specific code
}
```

Item class can have a Person reference like

```
public class Item {
  Person borrower;
  //More Item specific code
}
```

item should be extended by a class say `Media` and then you can construct specialized classes that inherit the `Media` class.

```
public class Media extends Item {
  //media specific code
}


public class Movie extends Media {
  public enum Quality {FULL_HD, HD};
  //more Movie specific code
}
```

this might give you a little idea..

Answer (score 1):

Think of **inheritance** as an "IS A(N)" relationship; think of **composition** as a "HAS A(N)" relationship.

Thinking in layman's terms, each book, movie, music CD, etc. IS AN item.

The library HAS A book, movie, etc; more precisely, the library HAS A collection of items.

Depending on your implementation, you may also say that a person HAS a collection of items, and the library has a collection of people (e.g. patrons or customers).  A person also HAS personal details like name and address, as you've shown above.

---

With that said, you would structure your classes using inheritance and composition as defined above.  Your resulting classes might look like this (showing just the fields and superclasses to give you an idea of how to use inheritance and composition accordingly):

```
class Library {
  Collection<Item> items;
  Collection<Person> customers;
}

class Person {
  Collection<Item> items;
  String name;
  String address;
}

class Item {
  String id;
  String name;
  // etc.
}

class Book extends Item {
  String author;
}

class MusicCD extends Item {
  String artist;
}

// etc.
```

Comment: this structure looks fine. problem is in item class constructor there is a String parameter of borrower name and the method addItemm called by main class which is passing all objects (like magazine, book, movie etc) so while defining addItem method in library class which class reference I should take to catch that object I cant take item class reference. I dont uderstand how to deal with it, I still stuck at addItem method of library class, Below I have shown my library and item class.  I think if I can solve this whole program will be easy for me. refer classes below in below posts.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the Person class. This should not extend anything.
Then you should go for a base class Library which contains the list of items and the persons if you want.
Then the item class. 
Then the Book Class which should extend the item class. Similarly the MusicCD, Movie, Magazine should extend the item class.

Comment: Yes I have changed accordingly, but can you tell me what parameter should be in addItem method in library class because in main class we are passing multiple objects of classes (book, Movies,.. etc). Also in main class they have created like Item[] = {new magazine(), new book(),...} with each of that instance have passed different datamembers. So the problem is while defining method addItem. (addItem(Item[i]) means if I catch this Item reference by any other class reference then it gives error which is correct and if I keep Item class only then it will omit remaining subclass data member).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers but the thing is class structure is fixed I just need to put write code for the given functions and apply inheritance to relate classes. And also there is a testdriver class which test all other classes and their execution so I need to write code according to testdriver class.

1) TestDriver class

```
    public class TestDriver {

public void runTestAddItem() {      
    System.out.println("***Testing addItem***");

    //by putting {} around each test we throw away all the variables created inside the braces when you get to the end of the test.   
    //Like a self cleaning mode.
    {
        System.out.println("-Test add an item and see if it is in the list-");
        String expected = "Found";
        System.out.println("Expected <"+expected+">");
        //Do the Test
        Library l1 = new Library();
        Item retrieved = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            l1.addItem(new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID001","Vanity Not So Faire", false,"New York", null, 5.95));
            retrieved = l1.findItem("ID001");
            //This will always come out true in this test as if there is an exception it will skip this line anyway.
            //It is in here for completeness and if someone writes another tests and uses this as an example.
            //The findItem should never return null but this will cover an event when something goes wrong in the library code 
            result = retrieved != null? "Found":"Not Found";
        } catch (DuplicateItemException e) {
            result = "Failed Duplicate Found";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Failed Exception Thrown";
        }           
        System.out.println("Got <"+result+">"); 
        if (result.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }

    {
        System.out.println("-Test add an item with a duplicate see if it throws an exception-");
        String expected = "Failed Duplicate Found";
        System.out.println("Expected <"+expected+">");
        //Do the Test
        Library l1 = new Library();
        Item retrieved = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            l1.addItem(new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID001","Vanity Not So Faire", false, "New York",null, 5.95));
            l1.addItem(new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID001","Vanity Not So Faire", false,"New Jersey", null, 5.95));
            retrieved = l1.findItem("ID001");
            result = retrieved != null? "Found":"Not Found";
        } catch (DuplicateItemException e) {
            result = "Failed Duplicate Found";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "Failed Exception Thrown";
        }           
        System.out.println("Got <"+result+">"); 
        if (result.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
    }

    //You need to write lots of tests here. 

}


public void runTestAddBorrower() {
    System.out.println("***Testing addBorrower***");
    {
        //use the first test as a template on how to write more
    }

}



public void runTestCountBorrowed() {
    System.out.println("***Testing countBorrowed***");

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestDriver td = new TestDriver();

    td.runTestAddItem();
    td.runTestAddBorrower();
    td.runTestCountBorrowed();
    //you need to add more


    td.arbitraryTestCode();
}



/**
 * This method just contains some dummy test code to check that basic functionality is working and also fail if the API is not created correctly in the Library file and Item file.



*/

    public void arbitraryTestCode() {
    Library l1 = new Library();
    Person p1 = null;
    try {
        p1 = new Person("Stewart","Mawson Lakes Blvd");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }   
    int id=0;
    try {
        Item[] testSubjects = {
                new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID00"+id++,"Vanity Not So Faire", false, "San Andreas",null, 5.95),
                new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID00"+id++,"Click", false, "San Andreas",null, 5.95),
                new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID00"+id++,"Renovate", false, "San Andreas",null, 5.95),
                new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID00"+id++,"Madrid", false, "San Andreas",null, 5.95),
                new Magazine(Magazine.frequency.day, "ID00"+id++,"Bikes", false, "San Andreas",null, 5.95),
                new MusicCD("Rudy Vale","Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new MusicCD("Rudy Vale The Third","Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 2 Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new MusicCD("Rudy Vale Sr","Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 3 Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new MusicCD("Rudy Vale Jr","Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 4 Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new MusicCD("Not Rudy Vale","Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 5 Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new MusicCD("Rudy Vale","Not Valen","ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 6 Soundtrack",false,null,19.95),
                new Bluray('c',Bluray.genre.drama,"ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 1 Revenge of the Fallen",false,null,29.95),
                new Bluray('c',Bluray.genre.drama,"ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 2 Ponies Are Ridden",false,null,29.95),
                new Bluray('c',Bluray.genre.drama,"ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 3 Sequels are Lame",false,null,29.95),
                new Bluray('c',Bluray.genre.drama,"ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 3 But They Keep Making Them",false,null,29.95),
                new Bluray('c',Bluray.genre.drama,"ID00"+id++,"Gatewars 5 They Make More Than is Reasonable",false,null,29.95),
                new DVD(1,DVD.genre.scifi,"ID00"+id++,"Darth Yobbit and the Range Runners",false,null,29.95),
                new DVD(1,DVD.genre.scifi,"ID00"+id++,"Darth Yobbit and the Long Jumpers",false,null,29.95),        
                new DVD(1,DVD.genre.scifi,"ID00"+id++,"Darth Yobbit and the Domain Walkers",false,null,29.95),      
                new DVD(1,DVD.genre.scifi,"ID00"+id++,"Darth Yobbit and the KiloByte",false,null,29.95),        
                new DVD(1,DVD.genre.scifi,"ID00"+id++,"Darth Yobbit and the Rabbits",false,null,29.95),     
                new Book("Arthur C Clarke","ID00"+id++,"The City and The Stars",false,null,14.50),
                new Book("Arthur C Clarke","ID00"+id++,"Rendevous With Rama",false,null,14.50),
                new Book("Arthur C Clarke","ID00"+id++,"2001",false,null,14.50)
        };

        for (int i=0;i<testSubjects.length;i++) {
            try {
                l1.addItem(testSubjects[i]);
            } catch(DuplicateItemException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("******");

        System.out.println(l1);
        l1.loanItem("ID0022", new Person("Stewart","Mawson Lakes"));
        System.out.println("Should say false "+l1.isBorrowed("ID0020"));
        System.out.println("Should say true "+l1.isBorrowed("ID0022"));
        System.out.println("Should say Stewart " + l1.getBorrower("ID0022").getName());
        System.out.println("Should say Mawson Lakes " + l1.getBorrower("ID0022").getAddress());

        System.out.println("******");

        //Various get datas from items
        System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID0020").getName());
        System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID0020").getId());
        System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID0020").getCost());
        System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID0020").getBorrower());
        System.out.println("Should be false "+l1.findItem("ID0020").isLoaned());
        l1.findItem("ID0020").setBorrower(new Person("AAA","ADDRESS"));
        //Corrected this.   BTW in normal operation this should not occur that there
        //is a borrower but not loaned.  This code is here to ensure that you have all 
        //The appropriate methods I need to check your code later.
        System.out.println("Should be false "+l1.findItem("ID0020").isLoaned());
        l1.findItem("ID0020").setCost(99.99f);
        l1.findItem("ID0020").setLoaned(false);
        l1.findItem("ID0020").setName("Changed Name");
        System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID0020"));

        System.out.println("******");


        try {
            System.out.println(l1.findItem("ID006"));
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("******");

        System.out.println("Number Borrowed "+l1.countBorrowed());
        System.out.printf("Percentage Borrowed %5.2f%% \n",l1.percentageBorrowed());
        try {
            l1.loanItem("ID001", p1);
            l1.loanItem("ID003", p1);
            l1.loanItem("ID004", p1);
            l1.loanItem("ID009", p1);
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("******");


        System.out.println("Number Borrowed Should say 5 "+l1.countBorrowed());
        System.out.printf("Percentage Borrowed %5.2f%% \n",l1.percentageBorrowed());

        System.out.println("Should say 10 "+l1.countMovies());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception Found in Input "+ex.getMessage());
    }

}
    }
```

```
This method should output 
Magazine [magazineFrequency=day, distributionCity=San Andreas, toString()=Item [id=ID000, name=Vanity Not So Faire, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=5.95]]
Magazine [magazineFrequency=day, distributionCity=San Andreas, toString()=Item [id=ID001, name=Click, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=5.95]]
Magazine [magazineFrequency=day, distributionCity=San Andreas, toString()=Item [id=ID002, name=Renovate, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=5.95]]
Magazine [magazineFrequency=day, distributionCity=San Andreas, toString()=Item [id=ID003, name=Madrid, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=5.95]]
Magazine [magazineFrequency=day, distributionCity=San Andreas, toString()=Item [id=ID004, name=Bikes, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=5.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID005, name=Gatewars Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale The Third, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID006, name=Gatewars 2 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale Sr, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID007, name=Gatewars 3 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale Jr, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID008, name=Gatewars 4 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Not Rudy Vale, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID009, name=Gatewars 5 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale, artist=Not Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID0010, name=Gatewars 6 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
Bluray [region=c, toString()=Movie [genre=drama, toString()=Item [id=ID0011, name=Gatewars 1 Revenge of the Fallen, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
Bluray [region=c, toString()=Movie [genre=drama, toString()=Item [id=ID0012, name=Gatewars 2 Ponies Are Ridden, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
Bluray [region=c, toString()=Movie [genre=drama, toString()=Item [id=ID0013, name=Gatewars 3 Sequels are Lame, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
Bluray [region=c, toString()=Movie [genre=drama, toString()=Item [id=ID0014, name=Gatewars 3 But They Keep Making Them, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
Bluray [region=c, toString()=Movie [genre=drama, toString()=Item [id=ID0015, name=Gatewars 5 They Make More Than is Reasonable, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0016, name=Darth Yobbit and the Range Runners, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0017, name=Darth Yobbit and the Long Jumpers, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0018, name=Darth Yobbit and the Domain Walkers, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0019, name=Darth Yobbit and the KiloByte, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0020, name=Darth Yobbit and the Rabbits, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=29.95]]]
Book [author=Arthur C Clarke, toString()=Item [id=ID0021, name=The City and The Stars, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=14.5]]
Book [author=Arthur C Clarke, toString()=Item [id=ID0022, name=Rendevous With Rama, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=14.5]]
Book [author=Arthur C Clarke, toString()=Item [id=ID0023, name=2001, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=14.5]]

Should say false false
Should say true true
Should say Stewart Stewart
Should say Mawson Lakes Mawson Lakes
     ******
Darth Yobbit and the Rabbits
ID0020
29.95
null
Should be false false
Should be false false
DVD [region=1, toString()=Movie [genre=scifi, toString()=Item [id=ID0020, name=Changed Name, loaned=false, borrower=Person [name=AAA, address=ADDRESS, toString()=unisa.library.Person@24a37368], cost=99.98999786376953]]]
     ******
MusicCD [composer=Rudy Vale The Third, artist=Valen, toString()=Item [id=ID006, name=Gatewars 2 Soundtrack, loaned=false, borrower=null, cost=19.95]]
     ******
Number Borrowed 1
Percentage Borrowed  4.17% 
     ******
Number Borrowed Should say 5 5
Percentage Borrowed 20.83% 
Should say 10 10
```

2) In Library class it is required to use ArrayList for items,

```
    public class Library {

    /**
    * itemList contains the List of all items in the library. 
    */
private ArrayList itemList;

/**
 * count of all the items in the library. 
 */
private int count;

public Library(){

}

/**
 * Add a new item to the list of items. 
 * @param newItem The new item to be added to the list.
 * @throws unisa.library.DuplicateItemException
 */

public void addItem(Item newItem) throws DuplicateItemException {
    itemList.add(newItem);
}

/**
 * Return the total number of items out on loan. 
 * @return The number representing the number of items currently on loan
 */

public int countBorrowed(){

    return 0;

}

/**
 * Return the number of Items that are either Blurays or DVDs 
 * @return the number of blurays and DVDs
 */
public int countMovies(){

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Find the item by the given ID and return that Item 
 * @param id The item to be returned
 * @return The item searched for.
 * @throws unisa.library.ItemNotFoundException thrown if the id is not found.
 */
public Item findItem(String id) throws ItemNotFoundException{

    return null;
}


/**
 * Gets the borrower of an item. If the item is not found throw ItemNotFoundException. 
 * @param id 
 * @return the borrower of the item. returns null if the item exists but is not borrowed.
 * @throws unisa.library.ItemNotFoundException thrown if the id is not found
 */
public Person getBorrower(String id) throws ItemNotFoundException{

    return null;
}


/**
 * Return the id of the given name. 
 * @param name the name of the item
 * @return the id of the item blank if not found.
 */
public String IDForName(String name){

    return null;
}


/**
 * Checks if a specific item is borrowed. 
 * @param id The id of the item that is to be checked.
 * @return the status of the item whether it is borrowed or not.
 * @throws unisa.library.ItemNotFoundException thrown if the id is not found.
 */
public boolean isBorrowed(String id) throws ItemNotFoundException{

    return false;
}


/**
 * Changes the status of the named item to borrowed and adds the Person to the borrowed
 * @param id The ID of the item to be borrowed
 * @param newPerson The borrower of the item
 * @throws unisa.library.ItemNotFoundException thrown if the id is not found.
 */
public void loanItem(String id, Person newPerson) throws ItemNotFoundException{

}

/**
 * Look up the name of the item based on the ID given. 
 * @param id The id of item searched for.
 * @return The name of the item blank if not found.
 */
public String nameForID(String id){

    return null;
}

/**
 * The percentage of the number of items that are out on loan. Expressed as a percentage of borrowed to total number of items.
 * @return the percentage borrowed.
 */
public double percentageBorrowed(){
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Changes the status of the named item to not borrowed and removes the user from the item. The borrower (person) is returned to the caller
 * @param id The id of the item
 * @return The person who borrowed the item
 * @throws unisa.library.ItemNotFoundException
 */
public Person returnItem(String id) throws ItemNotFoundException{
    return null;
}

    }
```

According this I have formed Item class

2) Item class has a constructor in which there is name of the borrower so to what I should assign this value.

```
    public class Item{
private String id;
private String name;
private boolean loaned;
private Person borrower;
private double cost;


public Item(String id, String name, boolean loaned, String borrower, double cost) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //borrower; ??
    this.id = id;
    this.name=name;
    this.loaned = loaned;
    this.cost = cost;
}

public String getID(String id){
    return id;
}
public String getName(String name){
    return name;
}
public boolean getLoaned(boolean loaned){
    return loaned;
}
public double getCost(double cost){
    return cost;
}




    }
```